# How to build voting classifier in sklearn when the individual classifiers are being fit with different datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I'm building a classifier using highly unbalanced data. The strategy I'm interesting in testing is ensembling a model using **3 different resampled datasets**. In other words, each dataset will have *all* the samples from the rare class, but *only* n samples of the abundant class ([technique #4 mentioned in this article](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/06/7-techniques-handle-imbalanced-data.html)).

I want to fit 3 different `VotingClassifiers` on each resampled dataset, and then combine the results of the individual models using *another* `VotingClassifier` (or similar). I know that building a single voting classifier looks like this:

```
# First Model
rnd_clf_1 = RandomForestClassifier()
xgb_clf_1 = XGBClassifier()

voting_clf_1 = VotingClassifier(
    estimators = [
        ('rf', rnd_clf_1), 
        ('xgb', xgb_clf_1),
    ],
    voting='soft'
)

# And I can fit it with the first dataset this way:
voting_clf_1.fit(X_train_1, y_train_1)
```

But how to stack the three of them if they are fitted on different datasets? For example, if I had three fitted models (see code below), I could build a function that calls the `.predict_proba()` method on each of the models and then "manually" averages the individual probabilities.

**But... is there a better way?**

```
# Fitting the individual models... but how to combine the predictions?
voting_clf_1.fit(X_train_1, y_train_1)
voting_clf_2.fit(X_train_2, y_train_2)
voting_clf_3.fit(X_train_3, y_train_3)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If it is a two class classification problem, then taking a mode of predictions would work fine.In case of more classes, we shall go for the prediction with highest probability but i am just thinking whether their probabilities would be comparable?

Comment: Hey @AdityaKansal, thanks for the comment. Actually, what I'm looking for is a way to combine the three voting classifiers using sklearn itself. I could make my own function that does what you suggest, but is there already a way to do it in sklearn, without having to reinvent the wheel? The difficulty that I have is that the models are fitted with different datasets, so I'm not sure a normal pipeline will do the work...

Answer (score 1):

Usually the #4 method shown in the article is implemented with same type of classifier. It looks like you want to try `VotingClassifier` on each sample dataset.

There is an implementation of this methodology already in [imblearn.ensemble.BalancedBaggingClassifier](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.ensemble.BalancedBaggingClassifier.html), which is an extension from Sklearn Bagging approach.

You can feed the estimator as `VotingClassifier` and number of estimators as the number of times, which you want carry out the dataset sampling. Use `sampling_strategy` param to mention proportion of downsampling which you want on Majority class.

Working Example:

```
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, VotingClassifier
from imblearn.ensemble import BalancedBaggingClassifier # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, class_sep=2,
weights=[0.1, 0.9], n_informative=3, n_redundant=1, flip_y=0,
n_features=20, n_clusters_per_class=1, n_samples=1000, random_state=10)
print('Original dataset shape %s' % Counter(y))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                    random_state=0)

rnd_clf_1 = RandomForestClassifier()
xgb_clf_1 = xgb.XGBClassifier()

voting_clf_1 = VotingClassifier(
    estimators = [
        ('rf', rnd_clf_1), 
        ('xgb', xgb_clf_1),
    ],
    voting='soft'
)

bbc = BalancedBaggingClassifier(base_estimator=voting_clf_1, random_state=42)
bbc.fit(X_train, y_train) # doctest: +ELLIPSIS

y_pred = bbc.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

See [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/ensemble/voting_classifier.py#L244). May be you can reuse `_predict_proba()` and `_collect_probas()` functions after fitting your estimators manually.